# Sequelize: transforming nested model in key/value object

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have a `Projects` model with a hasMany relation with `ProjectsTranslations`. I retrieve data with this query:

```
models.Projects.findById(req.params.id, {
    include: [
        {
            model: models.ProjectsTranslations,
        },
    ],
})
```

Which returns me this data:

```
{
    "Project": {
        "title": "First project",
        "id": 1,
        "ProjectsTranslations": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "First project",
                "ProjectId":1,
                "language": "en"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Primer proyecto",
                "ProjectId":1,
                "language": "es"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need the translations in this other format:

```
{
    "Project": {
        "title": "First project",
        "id": 1,
        "ProjectsTranslations": {
           "en": {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "First project",
                "ProjectId":1,
                "language": "en",
            },
            "es": {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Primer proyecto",
                "ProjectId":1,
                "language": "es"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do it in the model definition? There are no hooks for retrieving data —tried with `afterFind` hook without result—. Maybe a getter for the whole model —if this exists— or an instance method… But I'm not sure how to achieve that. Any help will be welcome!

Comment: AFAIK, this won't be possible in your model definition. However, it can easily be done in your controller code in JS. I can answer that if you would like.

Comment: Yep @mcranston18 , can be done in the controller, but It would be a bit of a mess to manipulate the data for every retrieved translation. That's why I'm looking for a way of doing it in the model definition, is easy to abstract it… By the why, I'm trying setting the hook afterFind in `ProjectsTranslations` model, but it don't trigger any action. Is it because this hook only works for finding one item?